# Asp.net core (cross-platform)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, cross-platform

Which thing makes asp.net core a cross-platform?I tried search on google but did'nt see anything regarding to this that what are the things that makes .net core a cross platform.

Comment: S.O. is not a discussion forum. It is for specific code related questions which have enough information so that others can reproduce your issue. Could you please edit your question?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has made a .net core runtime and a SDK that is compatible with Linux and MacOS. If you go to https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download you can download one of these products and start developing/running programs on a non Windows environment. In the past, there was no runtime that allowed you to execute .net program on such an operating system. You can see this on the downloads page: the only OS supported for framework 4.8 is Windows. If you want to start cross platform .net development, just open up a linux VM and install the appropriate runtime as well as visual studio code.